# Rails 5.2 MiniMagick::Error when using image variant with ratio and active storage

Tags: imagemagick, crop, ruby-on-rails-5.2

On my local the following code works fine from a view...

```
image_tag image.variant(combine_options: {resize:"1200", gravity: "Center", crop: "6:3"})
```

On production Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 it errors...

> MiniMagick::Error (`mogrify -gravity Center -crop 6:3 /tmp/mini_magick20180806-26536-1n7pdkl.jpg` failed with error: mogrify-im6.q16: invalid geometry `6:3' @error/geometry.c/ParseGravityGeometry/1185.):

Really hoping someone has a solution here as the crop method by defining a ratio works perfectly for my purposes.

If I change the code to...

```
image_tag image.variant(combine_options: {gravity: "Center", crop: "1200x800+0+0"})
```

I don't get an error but I also don't get the results I am after.

I am at a total loss as I can't duplicate it in my dev env. I have updated ImageMagick and MiniMagick on server to same version as on my local. Can't think of what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

based on that http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop crop is accepting geometry argument. Geometry is described here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

My impression is that your ratio should be described as "3:2~" not "3:2"

Comment: actually, that command works well on my local mogrify -gravity Center -crop 10:1 test.png so looks like something is wrong with image magic. Do you know what version of image magic you got?

Comment: Thanks @lis2! Here are image magik details on server...
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

Comment: there you go! I installed imagemagick on my mac and everything is fine because it installs imagemagick 7.0.8-10. And look on changelog here https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php - they added aspect ratio geometry 2018-01-07 - version 7.0.7 . Bad news is that I couldn't find a way to install it via apt-get, people are compiling it from source - https://medium.com/@sanjaywrites/install-latest-version-of-imagemagick-in-ubuntu-16-04-c406ddea1973

Comment: I have already notified the ImageMagick developers of a potential bug in the aspect ratio crop in recent versions of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @lis2
Upgrading to lastest version of ImageMagick did the trick.
Follow along here if anyone needs to do it... [https://linuxhint.com/imagemagick-bitmap-images-editor/][1]
Works on Ubuntu 18 as well as 14 and 16.

ssh into server then

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-7.0.*
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

The way above leaves me without the delegates to resolve png and jpegs.
Doing the following works...

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar -xvf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-7.0.*
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
./configure --enable-shared
make libdir=/usr/lib
sudo make libdir=/usr/lib install
./configure --enable-shared=yes --x-libraries=/usr/lib --without-perl
make
sudo make install
```

Now when I do identify -version I get... 
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-12 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-27 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

Cheers
Dan